# How to keep razor variable in context in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my view code.

```
@{
     string file = "~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png";
     if (File.Exists(file))
     { 
        var imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
     }
     else
     { 
        var imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Default_Profile.png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
     }

 }
   <img src="@imgUrl" height="50" width="50" />
```

I am getting an error in my src attribute as shown in the line below

```
<img src="@imgUrl" height="50" width="50" />
```

I am getting an error saying that imgUrl is not in context. How do I resolve this? I tried using `<span>` and I also tried putting this in {}, but nothing worked. I also tried quotes for src attribute, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Declare imgUrl **outside** the scope of your if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your `imgUrl` variable outside the `if` statement as it is in its own scope.

```
@{
    string file = "~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png";
    var imgUrl = string.Empty;
    if (File.Exists(file))
    { 
         imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
    }
    else
    { 
         imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Default_Profile.png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
    }

    <img src="@imgUrl" height="50" width="50" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @{
      string imgUrl = string.Empty;
      string file = "~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png";
      if (File.Exists(file))
      { 
          imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + ".png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
      }
      else
      { 
         imgUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Default_Profile.png") + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
      }
      <img src="@imgUrl" height="50" width="50" />
    }
```

Comment: Adding an explanation would help differentiate this answer from the other two already existing, identical ones.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare `imgUrl` variable outside the if and else scope.